# Google AdMob for react native

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, admob

After installing ad mob ([installed from this](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob)) and link it to my react native project, my app crash.
What is the best way to add google ad mob with the latest react native version?

P.s. can you show me all of the steps to get a working admob application?

Answer (score 0):

Do what that link said you to do.

Then just complete another small step

Goto

node-module/react-native-admob/android/build.gradle file replace the line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
```

with the following line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, now on the emulator I get this warning and the banner(testAd), but when I create the APK for my phone the banner in no longer visible.      https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dnlj4Q6nY9wwm5xOnFgJjlcUBoBgAjpo

Comment: without looking at your code snippet can not help you buddy.

Comment: You're rigth, I've updated my drive folder with the content of my project